Unit Test Axios Interceptors On Typescript
I'm trying to unit test axios interceptors to see what happens when there is a token, there is no token and for error cases. I use sinon when needed to stub something. I checked other topics how to test axios interceptors and tried like that but couldn't succeed. Here is the code I'm trying to unit test.
Also I should say that I do not want to make an integration test.
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestHeaders } from 'axios'
import logger from './logging'

const myInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com',
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'example' },
})

myInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => {
        const token = process.env.EXAMPLE_TOKEN
        request.headers = {
            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        } as AxiosRequestHeaders

        return request
    },
    (error) => {
        logger.error(error)
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)

export default { myInstance }

Here is the test I coded. But I can not even run the test because I get "Property 'handlers' does not exist on type 'AxiosInterceptorManager<InternalAxiosRequestConfig>'" error. But as much as I see most there are some examples that uses interceptors.request.handlers[0].fulfilled(). My axios version is 1.6.3
Why I can not use that? Also I checked the index.d.cts and index.d.ts files of axios in node modules and there is no handlers type defined but I see people using this approach on testing axios interceptors. What am I missing? Or my approach to testing is all wrong? Or do you have any other suggestion on testing axios interceptors?
import { createSandbox, assert } from 'sinon'
import logger from './logging'
import api from '../utils/axios'

const sandbox = createSandbox()

describe('My Tests', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore()
        delete process.env.EXAMPLE_TOKEN
    })

    describe('myInstance Interceptor Tests', () => {
        it('should set header successfully if there is a EXAMPLE_TOKEN', async () => {
            process.env.EXAMPLE_TOKEN = 'exampleToken'
            const result =
                api.myInstance.interceptors.request.handlers[0].fulfilled({
                    headers: {},
                })
            expect(result.headers.Authorization).toEqual('Bearer exampleToken')
        })

        it('should set header as "" if there is no EXAMPLE_TOKEN', async () => {
            delete process.env.EXAMPLE_TOKEN
            const result =
                api.myInstance.interceptors.request.handlers[0].fulfilled({
                    headers: {},
                })
            expect(result.headers.Authorization).toEqual('')
        })

        it('should log error if there is error during setting header', async () => {
            delete process.env.EXAMPLE_TOKEN
            const loggerErrorStub = sandbox.spy(logger, 'error')
            try {
                api.myInstance.interceptors.request.handlers[0].reject(
                    new Error('Unexpected Error!')
                )
            } catch (error: any) {
                expect(error.message).toEqual('Unexpected Error!')
                assert.calledWith(loggerErrorStub, error)
            }
        })
    })
})


I have the same issue
